# Qt VideoWidget example

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, video, qt5

I am using Qt5 and I found [this example code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html) , but I need to show video in some of available Qt visual objects, in which objects I can use this video overview code with VideoWidget? I am Qt beginner, and I am trying to understand how Qt works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, a QVideoWidget inherits from QWidget, you can put in a window or in another widget.
There's an example "videowidget" project in the Examples directory of the Qt sources.

A minimal exemple:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication testApp(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    QVideoWidget videoWidget(&w);
    w.setCentralWidget(&videoWidget);

    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(&w);

    player->setMedia( QUrl::fromLocalFile("E:\\big_buck_bunny.mp4") );
    player->setVideoOutput(&videoWidget);

    w.show();

    player->play();

    return testApp.exec();
}
```

test_video.pro:

```
QT       += core gui widgets multimedia multimediawidgets

TARGET = test_video

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: This exact code in windows is not displaying any video for me.

Comment: @camccar do you have a local "E:\\big_buck_bunny.mp4" video file ?

Comment: Yes I do I think my problem was a missing qt5multimediawidgets.dll. So now I need to figure out how to install that.